# Update TextView in ListView in real time

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having a problem updating a `TextView` in real time. I want to update the `TextView` of a `ListView` with a custom adapter in real time. I have my socket I/O handler on which I receive a JSON message. I want to parse this JSON and put that text into the particular list row with `setText()`. How do I get the index of that `ListView` row and update its `TextView`?

```
responseid=object.getString("ResponseID");
if(responseid!=null){
    for(int j=0;j<countryList.size();j++){
        //If the countryList row match then i want to update the textView of that particular row
        if(countryList.get(j).getName().equals(caseid)) {                        
            int oldcount = Integer.parseInt((dataAdapter.findViewById(R.id.replycount)).getText().toString());
            int total=oldcount+1;
            (dataAdapter.findViewById(R.id.replycount)).setText(Integer.toString(total));
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }    
}
```

**Here is my solution:**

```
for(int j=0;j<countryList.size();j++)
{
    if(countryList.get(j).getName().equals(caseid))
    {
        String oldcount = countryList.get(j).getCount();
        int oldcountint = Integer.parseInt(oldcount);
        int newcount = oldcountint + 1;
        countryList.get(j).setCount(Integer.toString(newcount));
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should alter the items in your `ListAdapter`, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Example:

```
//Creating and adding ListAdapter to ListView
MyObject myFirstObject = new MyObject("Test1");
MyObject mySecondObject = new MyObject("Test2");

MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
myAdapter.add(myFirstObject);
myAdapter.add(mySecondObject);
myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

When updating a particular position:

```
myAdapter.getItem(position).text = "My updated text";
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```